# Inserting data into database with Tagging system? For someone who is picking up HTML after 20 years

Tags: php, html, database, tagging

I'm building a HTML/PHP front end to curate & navigate my locally stored media. I learned HTML **basics** back in school and understand this may not be the optimum approach for a such a task but please bare with me.

Over the last few weeks, I have managed to build out a navigational structure and with the help of articles here, w3 schools & YouTube videos some neat features..

1. Two sticky navbars with hover over drop-downs
2. Change IMG attributes when clicking a button and randomly select images from an array on refresh
3. Displaying data from myPHP database in a responsive bootstrap table with Filters
4. **HTML form to input data into the same database.**

I've created a "mock" tagging system by using 10 x Table columns (Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3). It works, kind of but the form has far too many fields. I'd like the ability (in the input form) to combine those 10 separate column fields into one with a tagging system (that allows Max 10 tags) and maintain the ability to load those tags into the db record.

I've found a bunch of guides that show how to build the working tag system but havent managed to find one that shows how to load that into a database.

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn next about database normalisation and foreign key relationships. Once you understand that, a solution is likely to present itself more easily

Comment: To add to @ADyson, do some research there, and you'll probably end up with a table like `tags (id, name)`, and then a table `media_tags (media_id, tag_id)` in which you could have multiple rows associating the multiple tag IDs to a single Media ID. Use PHP to enforce the maximum number of tags.